# "No JDK found. Please validate ...JAVA_HOME...."-message with desktop launcher in ubuntu but works in shell

Tags: java, android, ubuntu, android-studio

I recently installed android-studio on my machine (ubuntu 16.04). After configurating my .bashrc file (JAVA_HOME is also set there), it starts in in my shell. 
I also wanted to create a launcher on my desktop, so i created a androidstudio.desktop file in ~/.local/share/applications/.

Here is my .desktop entry:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Name=AndroidStudio
Exec=/home/<path to android-studio>/bin/studio.sh
Icon=/home/<path to android-studio>/bin/studio.png
Terminal=false
Categorie=Development
```

The icon appears on my desktop but when I launch android-studio now, I get the following Error:

```
No JDK found. Please validate either STUDIO_JDK, JDK_HOME or JAVA_HOME environment variable points to valid JDK installation.
```

Comment: What's the value of JAVA_HOME env. variable? Do a printenv from there and see

Comment: It`s /usr/local/java

Answer (score 0):

You can set environment variables for your **.desktop** entry, see r.g. https://askubuntu.com/a/144971

TL;NR:

```
Exec=env JAVA_HOME=/usr/local/java /home/<path to android-studio>/bin/studio.sh
```

Comment: It didn't work for me either. Maybe something is wrong with my Java installation. I put the java folder in /usr/local/lib and made a softlink in /usr/local/java.
Then I set the JAVA_HOME variable in my ~/.bashrc file. I didn't use the update-alternatives method...

Comment: Yes it works in command line. Even when i use the Android Studio feature -> create desktop entry...it doesn't work. I've read (don't know the source anymore) that .bashrc is only for bash and if i want to make changes to the launcher i have to use /etc/profile and i tried it but it changed the result at all.

Comment: right, `.bashrc` cannot help; I don't know what is wrong with the `.desktop` entry. Maybe, your command line defines **JAVA_HOME** differently, or adds some other environment variables that are needed (check **STUDIO_JDK**, **JDK_HOME**, etc). Maybe, `studio.sh` does something unexpected with its environment.